# How to remove or increase timeout from JavaScript fetch method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timeout, frontend, fetch

I have a JavaScript React client and Java backend. So, when I'm trying to debug my backend, I run into a problem with fetch timeout (20 seconds). And my question is, can I remove this timeout or increase it in some way? Thanks in advance :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check why this Timed_Out error happened? The ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error means there is something not good with your connection or communication error.

Comment: It's happened while debugging controller on the backend.

Comment: Try form other browsers.Try increase the timeout if you are using ajax calls. $.ajax({
    url: "../../",
    error: function(){
        //Error code
    },
    success: function(){
        //Success code
    }
   timeout: 10000 // 10 seconds
});

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using fetch API, is there something about timeout?

Comment: How you are fetching API?